# Input type file breaks container causing horizontal scroll (bootstrap 4 beta)

Tags: css, forms, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create two 6 column divs. The second div has a form that should be 4 columns and centered. Everything works fine until I add the file input to the form. This causes it to break out of the container and adds a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom. I read that changing css for input{overflow:hidden;} would fix this but it did not. I've commented out the input file line so that it can be found easier. Can someone tell me how to keep the file input from breaking outside the box.

```
<div class="container careers-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 mx-auto mt-4">
           <h1 class='carbon cyan text-center'>Careers</h1>
           <div class="divider background-cyan"></div>
           <p class='salmon mt-4 font-24'>The Bridge is a premier pool hall providing an exceptional experience to it's clientele. We have the best tables, a great selection of drinks, good food options and lots of entertainment in a classy atmosphere. We are currently looking for people with service industry experience to serve at our Edmond location.</p>
           <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-12">
                       <h2 class='zaffre h5'>Currently Hiring</h2>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row no-gutters">
                   <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 d-none d-sm-block">
                       <img src="images/dart-board.jpg" class='img-fluid mb-3'></img>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
                       <ul class='list-unstyled zaffre ml-3'>
                            <li>Bar Manager</li>
                            <li>Full time bartenders</li>
                            <li>Part time bartenders</li>
                            <li>Full or part time cooks</li>
                            <li>Part time cocktail waitress</li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                     <span class='zaffre h6 font-24'>Please submit your resume here and we will contact you</span>  
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 mx-auto">
            <div class="background-cyan pt-3 pb-3 pl-1 pr-1">
               <form>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label sr-only">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Full Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="tel-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label sr-only">Telephone</label>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="tel" value="Phone Number" id="tel-input">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label sr-only">EMAIL</label>
                          <div class="col-12">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                             <label class='text-white' for="InputFile">Upload Resume</label>
    <!--                        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="InputFile"/>   -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button type="submit" id='submit-btn' class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary mt-5 info-button">Submit Form</button>
                    </div>
                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--End of container-->
```

[image: Ipad Breakout]

Comment: Can you show the CSS you tried? When I add `overflow:hidden` it works ¹. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/d2xybfqk/). So maybe you used the wrong selector.

Comment: ¹ That is, it works as in: there is no more horizontal scrollbar. You can't see the filename in the control any more though, so I think I like the version with the scrollbar better.

Comment: First let me apologize for the length of time between, I forgot I was going out of town when I posted this. Second, I think you must be right I may have had a bad selector because I retyped the property but put it in the body instead of input and the scroll bar is not there. But I am experiencing a second problem. You can see in the photo it breaks out of the form. Also, even with scroll hidden can pull the screen left and have a lot of white space on the right. How can I keep this from breaking out of the form container at all even at mobile and ipad size.